# jQuery refer to the loaded object inside load's callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

The goal is to load a `html`'s content inside a `button`, and when the load is 
finished, refer back to the object just loaded (in my case it's the variable 
`box`), and change its `div`s' texts, whom I can find by ID. At the end, add 
the `box` so `css` can be applied.

Here's what I was trying:

```
var box = $('<button>').load('\\html\\tile.html', 
function () 
{
    box.find('#eventName').html(myEvents[i].name);            
    box.find('#eventDate').html(myEvents[i].date);
    box.find('#eventTime').html(myEvents[i].time);
    box.find('#description').html(myEvents[i].description);
}).addClass('box');
```

To make it more complete, here's `tile.html`:

```
<div>
    <div id='eventName'>Event name</div>
    <div id='eventDate>2017.01.01.</div>
    <div id='eventTime'>12.00</div>
    <div id='description'>Some boring example description about the meaningless events you endure.</div>
</div>
```

I request assistance to change the just loaded object's div contents.

Right now I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>   at HTMLButtonElement. (alap.js:40)
>   at HTMLButtonElement. (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
>   at Function.each (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
>   at r.fn.init.each (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
>   at Object. (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
>   at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
>   at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
>   at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
>   at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)

Comment: `myEvents` is undefined in that funtion() , the callback must be written like : `function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr)` see the jquery documentation http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. So from those variables how do I get the `myEvents`'s items?

Comment: @Timmetje ? I looked up the documentation but it didn't say anything about using a variable defined outside of that function().